# SQL: Combine two count queries into one

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently I have two sql queries with each returning the total count of a certain column for a specific date:

```
select first_name COUNT(*) as totalCount from some_table
where the_date >= '2020-09-14' and the_date <='2020-09-15' 
group by first_name

select first_name COUNT(*) as totalCount from some_table
where the_date >= '2020-09-16' and the_date <='2020-09-17' 
group by first_name
```

Each will return a table such as:

`first_name | totalCount`

Instead, I would like one query that returns results as such:

`first_name | count1 | count2`

With count1 being the total count for the first query and count2 being the total count for the second query

I tried:

```
select first_name COUNT(*) as count1 from some_table
where the_date >= '2020-09-14' and the_date <='2020-09-15' 
group by first_name
UNION
select first_name COUNT(*) as count2 from some_table
where the_date >= '2020-09-16' and the_date <='2020-09-17' 
group by first_name
```

But it still returned results of count1 only.

Comment: Have you tried UNION?

Comment: @Mech I did, let me add what I tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE the_date >= '2020-09-14' AND the_date < '2020-09-15') AS totalCount1,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE the_date >= '2020-09-16' AND the_date < '2020-09-17') AS totalCount2
FROM some_table
GROUP BY
    first_name;
```

Note that I am using an inequality looking something like the following:

```
the_date >= '2020-09-14' AND the_date < '2020-09-15'
```

This will target exactly the date `'2020-09-14'` only.

**Edit:**

To your follow-up question in the comments below, if you want to match first names which only have both counts as zero, use:

```
SELECT
    first_name
FROM some_table
GROUP BY
    first_name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE the_date >= '2020-09-14' AND the_date < '2020-09-15' OR
                           the_date >= '2020-09-16' AND the_date < '2020-09-17') = 0;
```

Comment: This is great!! How can I filter out when both totalCount1 and totalCount2 at the same time are 0?

Comment: @MohamadZein Check the updated answer, hope this helps.

Comment: oh I meant from the first query you wrote, I want to filter out the rows which has both totalCount1 column and totalCount2 column as 0 (when both at the same time)

Comment: ...and the query on the bottom of my answer is doing this `:-)`